# how to use -moz-focus-inner in ADF to remove dotted outline of button in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Here I am using Oracle ADF.
My button is styled as follows:

```
af|commandButton:text-only {
    background-image: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #c4ced7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 10px 3px 10px;
}

af|commandButton:text-only:focus {
    background-image: none;
    width: auto;
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #c4ced7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 10px 3px 10px;
}
```

Removed focus outline using "**outline:none;**" as specified in the CSS snippet.
Now, focus outline is removed in all browsers except firefox.
As per the diagnosis I found that firefox uses "**-moz-focus-inner**" to render outline.

I tried the following two ways in CSS but no luck.

First way:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

Second way:

```
af|commandButton:text-only:focus::-moz-focus-inner,
af|commandButton:focus::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
}
```

How to specify styles for "-moz-focus-inner" in  ADF ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my xul programm. The point was, that there was some shadow DOM hidden in the button, which has the dotted border.

This is how I made it work:

```
button *, button:focus *
{
    border: 0;
}
```

Keep in mind, that the element within the button has a transparent border when the button is not in the :focus state. Therefor you have either to clear it for both states or just set the border to transparent too at :focus.

Hope that helps you too